# How to determine what attributes changed on sync

Tags: backbone.js

As the title says, is there any way for me to determine what attributes on my model changed when synced?

For me the ideal situation would be a mechanism that functions like the `change` listener, so I'd have something like:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize: function(){
        this.on({
            'sync:Name' : 'onSyncName'
        })

        onSyncName: function(){
            alert('Name saved!');
        }
    }
})
```

From what I can tell this mechanism doesn't exist for individual attributes as a whole, `sync` will only refer to the entire model itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [changedAttribute](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-changedAttributes) function from the model which returns a hash of the attributes changed from last set.

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

   initialize: function(){
      this.on({
        'sync' : 'onSync'
      });        
   },
   onSync: function(model){
        _.each( model.changedAttributes(), function(value, key, list) { console.log("key" + key + " value " + value);
   }

})
```

The sync event for only an attribute doesn't exist and doesn't make sense as it is the whole model which is syncing

Comment: As stated in the documentation (https://devdocs.io/backbone/index#Model-changedAttributes), changedAttributes only returns attributes that have changed since the last set (and not since the last sync).

Answer (score 0):

You could add a **validate** method in your Model and use it to save the changed attributes inside a variable:

```
            var lastChanged = {};
            var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

                initialize: function(){
                    this.on({
                        'sync' : 'onSync'
                    });
                },

                onSync: function(){
                    if(lastChanged.hasOwnProperty("Name")){
                        alert("Name changed!");
                    }
                },

                validate : function(attrs, options){
                    lastChanged = options.changed;
                }

            });
```